# how do I make the base of each UIView a tangent to a circle so they radiate from the centre?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, rotation

I am trying to find angles of rotation for a series of light and dark rectangular `UIViews` placed at regular points on a circle perimeter. Each point on the circle is calculated as an angle of displacement from the centre and I have tried using the same angle to rotate each `UIView` so it radiates from the centre. But I didn't expect it to look like this.

[image]

I expected the angle of displacement from the centre to be the same as the angle of rotation for each new `UIView`. Is this assumption correct ? and if so, how do I make the base of each `UIView` a tangent to a circle so they radiate from the centre ?

**UPDATE**

In case someone finds it useful here is an update of my original code. The problem [as explained by rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48375734/2348597) has been rectified.

I’ve included two versions of the transform statement and their resulting rotated UIViews. Result on the left uses `radians + arcStart + M_PI / 2.0`, result on right uses `radians + arcStart`.

[image]

Here is the method.

```
- (void)sprocket
{
CGRect  canvas                      = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
CGPoint circleCentre                = CGPointMake((canvas.size.width)/2, (canvas.size.height)/2);

CGFloat width                       = 26.0f;
CGFloat height                      = 50.0f;

CGPoint miniViewCentre;

CGFloat circleRadius                = 90;
int miniViewCount                   = 16;

for (int i = 0; i < miniViewCount; i++)
{
    // to place the next view calculate angular displacement along an arc

    CGFloat circumference           = 2 * M_PI;
    CGFloat radians                 = circumference * i / miniViewCount;

    CGFloat arcStart                = M_PI + 1.25f; // start circle from this point in radians;

    miniViewCentre.x                = circleCentre.x + circleRadius * cos(radians + arcStart);
    miniViewCentre.y                = circleCentre.y + circleRadius * sin(radians + arcStart);

    CGPoint placeMiniView           = CGPointMake(miniViewCentre.x, miniViewCentre.y);

    CGRect swivellingFrame          = CGRectMake(placeMiniView.x, placeMiniView.y, width, height);
    UIView *miniView                = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:swivellingFrame];

    if ((i % 2) == 0)
    {
        miniView.backgroundColor    = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    }
    else
    {
        miniView.backgroundColor    = [UIColor grayColor];
    }

    miniView.layer.borderWidth      = 1;
    miniView.layer.borderColor      = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    miniView.layer.cornerRadius     = 3;
    miniView.clipsToBounds          = YES;
    miniView.layer.masksToBounds    = YES;
    miniView.alpha                  = 1.0;

    // using the same angle rotate the view around its centre

    miniView.transform              = CGAffineTransformRotate(miniView.transform, radians + arcStart  + M_PI / 2.0);

    [page1 addSubview:miniView];
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your calculation of the center of each miniView is based on `radians` plus `arcStart` but the transform of each miniView is only based on `radians`.

Also note that angle `0` is at the 3 o'clock position of the circle. You actually want a 90° (or π/2 radians) rotation of `miniView` so the rectangle "sticks out" from the circle.

You need two small changes to make your code work:

Change the loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < miniViewCount; i++)
```

And change the transform:

```
miniView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(miniView.transform, radians + arcStart + M_PI / 2.0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. The second change solved it. I got it working using either i = 0 and i = 1. Was there a reason why you recommended starting the loop from 0 ? And so I understand your second change correctly, there needs to be a 90° difference between the angle of displacement from the centre and the angle for rotating each miniView. Is that correct ?

Comment: Remove the ` + M_PI / 2.0` and see the difference. Your rectangles are still in the correct place but pointing the wrong way. Swapping the width and height is another option. I like to start loops with 0, not 1. I've been programming for a long time and I am used to indexes starting at 0.

Comment: That's fantastic! And to think I tried doing this using UIImage. This approach wins hands down. Many thanks.